# reshape a dataframe based on suffix with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I need to 'reshape' a dataframe based on a suffix of the X column.

```
X    Y
a_1  12
b_1  20
c_1  30
a_2  2
b_2  56
c_2  70
d_2  2
```

And obtain :

```
    _1   _2
a   12   2
b   20   56
c   30   70
d   0    2
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.X.str.split(r'_', expand=True)
     .assign(y=df.Y.values)
     .pivot(0,1,'y')
     .fillna(0)
     .astype(int))

1   1   2
0        
a  12   2
b  20  56
c  30  70
d   0   2
```

Comment: Yatu, Thank you for your quick and efficient answer.